# WebStorm remove newline in empty classes/functions

Tags: webstorm

I'm using WebStorm and I want to remove the newline in empty classes/functions. I couldn't find a related question.

```
export class AppRoutingModule {
}

=>

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Enabling **Keep when reformatting | Simple blocks in one line** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript (Typescript) | Wrapping and Braces** will make the formatter keep the empty classes "as is" (i.e. not insert a new line). But there is no way to remove existing line breaks from such classes on re-formatting